# How to add a method to all django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

What is the best way to add a method-like functionality to all templates in my project?

The method that I need is the following:

```
def has_access(user, code):
    return user has access to code
```

Within a template it woule be used like so:

```
{% if has_access(request.user, 'add-project') %}
    html code here
{% endif %}
```

Custom filters won't work since I am not "filtering" anything. Also, from what I can see, custom context processors don't accept extra parameters.

Not sure how to go about doing this in django.

Comment: Need more info. Particularly, what is it you're trying to achieve? What does "has access to code" mean? The user can access the view in their browser?

Comment: Depending on what `code` is/does, this could be something [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs#writing-your-own-middleware) can solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom filters actually would work:

```
{{ user|has_access:code }}
```

A custom template tag would work:

```
{% has_access user code %}
```

A middleware could work... but it is hard to say what's the best method for your problem without having more info.

Comment: Can either of those be used within an if statement?

Comment: @Ramin, the filter can be used. {% if user|has_access:code %}